# Can I skip files using Keras ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory on MacOS?

Tags: python, keras

I've downloaded an image set with 10 images in each of 7 classes for a total of 70 images. However, each of the class folders now has 20 files in it: a `._` (dot-underscore) file has been created for each individual .jpeg file. I'm only able to see these if I run an `os.listdir()`, meaning I can't see them using the Finder. I could try to move them using the `os` command, but I'm not sure what that would do to the system.

Is it possible to work around these `._` files in any way?

`['51.jpeg',
 '._.DS_Store',
 '._57.jpeg',
 '._56.jpeg',
 '.DS_Store',
 '50.jpeg',
 '._51.jpeg',
 '57.jpeg',
 '56.jpeg',
 '._50.jpeg',
 '._53.jpeg',
 '59.jpeg',
 '55.jpeg',
 '54.jpeg',
 '58.jpeg',
 '._52.jpeg',
 '._59.jpeg',
 '53.jpeg',
 '._55.jpeg',
 '._54.jpeg',
 '52.jpeg',
 '._58.jpeg']`

**EDIT: Added code for ImageDataGenerator**

```
def generator(set_type, TARGET_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, CLASSES, RANDOM_SEED):
    '''
    set_type (str): "train", "test", "validation"
    returns: ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory
    '''
    data_dir = './' + set_type + '_data_keras'
    return ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(data_dir,
                                                    target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
                                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    classes = CLASSES,
                                                    seed = RANDOM_SEED)


TARGET_SIZE = (224, 224)
BATCH_SIZE = 5
CLASSES = ['5', '10', '20', '50', '100', '200', '500']
RANDOM_SEED = 0

train_generator = generator('train', TARGET_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE,
                            CLASSES, RANDOM_SEED)
validation_generator = generator('validation', TARGET_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE,
                                 CLASSES, RANDOM_SEED)
```

`flow_from_directory` is looking for a directory to search for `CLASSES`, so I'm looking for a way to bypass the `._` files

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve the initial problem, but I did find a work around. I was able to go back to the .tar.gz file and only extract files that met the criteria I needed:

```
def download_images(url, file_name):
'''
Downloads and extracts file if it is not in current directory
'''
if file_name not in os.listdir():
    print('Downloading and extracting: ' + file_name)
    wget.download(url, file_name)
    tar = tarfile.open(file_name, mode = 'r:gz')
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        if '._' in member.name:
            continue
        else:
            tar.extract(member)
    tar.close()
```

I will leave this question open in case someone knows an answer to the original post, but for now this is getting me where I need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late here, but for anyone still looking for an answer:
you can get the valid filenames along with their labels in a dataframe, and then use the `flow_from_dataframe` function instead of `flow_from_directory`.
This function takes  `dataframe, directory, x_col = image_names/paths, y_col=labels` as arguments. Rest of the functionality is exactly identical to 'flow_from_directory'.
You can find more information with examples in the official docs here: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can filter your files. I added three different solutions:

```
files = ['51.jpeg', '._.DS_Store', '._57.jpeg', '._56.jpeg', '.DS_Store',
         '50.jpeg', '._51.jpeg', '57.jpeg', '56.jpeg', '._50.jpeg', '._53.jpeg',
         '59.jpeg', '55.jpeg', '54.jpeg', '58.jpeg', '._52.jpeg', '._59.jpeg',
         '53.jpeg', '._55.jpeg', '._54.jpeg', '52.jpeg', '._58.jpeg']
```

Filter by string matching:

```
[f for f in files if str(f).strip().endswith('.jpeg') and not str(f).strip().startswith('._')]
# ['51.jpeg', '50.jpeg', '57.jpeg', '56.jpeg', '59.jpeg', '55.jpeg', '54.jpeg', '58.jpeg', '53.jpeg', '52.jpeg']
```

Filter by string matching with `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda f: str(f).strip().endswith('.jpeg') and not str(f).strip().startswith('._'), files))
# ['51.jpeg', '50.jpeg', '57.jpeg', '56.jpeg', '59.jpeg', '55.jpeg', '54.jpeg', '58.jpeg', '53.jpeg', '52.jpeg']
```

Filter by a regular expression with `filter`:

```
import re
list(filter(lambda f: re.match(r"^(?!\.)[\w]+(\.jpeg)$", f), files))
# ['51.jpeg', '50.jpeg', '57.jpeg', '56.jpeg', '59.jpeg', '55.jpeg', '54.jpeg', '58.jpeg', '53.jpeg', '52.jpeg']
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more specific. `ImageDataGenerator()` is looking specifically for a directory of images. From the documentation: _directory: Path to the target directory. It should contain one subdirectory per class. Any PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator._ See edits to OP